# Gamma Function Representation

Tags: integration, analysis

I have some questions relating to the gamma function.

My question is simply to evaluate the integral $$\int_0^\infty {t^{z-1}\sin t}\,dt$$

whenever $-1<\text{Re}(z)<1$.

If we  take $z$ real and define a function $f$ s.t. $f(t) = t^{z-1}e^{it}$ and integrate it along the contour $C$ which is consisting of the first quadrant that indented at the origin, then we reached that $$\Gamma(z) e^{i \pi z/2} = \int_0^\infty t^{z-1} e^{it}\, dt $$ whenever $0<\text{Re}(z)<1$.

First question is that where $-1<\text{Re}(z)<1$ comes from?

My second question is while we are evaluating the integral of $f$ along the contour $C$ , on the small arc, I have some doubts of letting the radius of the small arc to $0$, what I want to be sure that, call that arc $C_e$,  $\int_{C_e} f(t)dt$ is convergent, In other words in our case $f(t) = t^{z-1}e^{it}$, as $t$ tends to $0$, how can we guarantee that the integral converges, actually I have  solved that part by letting $t = \epsilon.e^{i\theta}$ then finding a upper bound for the integrand, but i confused in this part.

But my main question as I have mentioned above, where $-1<\text{Re}(z)<1$ comes from?

Comment: this conditions just ensure that your function is integrable at $0$ and $\infty$
and the small arc is vansihing exaxtly because of the above conditions.

Comment: Yes, but how? My main question is infact after finding $\Gamma(z) e^{i \pi z/2} = \int_0^\infty t^{z-1} e^{it}\ dt$ for $0<Rez<1$ how to extend it to $-1<Rez<1$, analytic continuation or uniqueness theorem should play a role here, but i could not figure it out.

Comment: At infinity the integrand is integrable by Jordan's Lemma. At zero it diverges with $t^a$, $a>-1$ and therefore the singularity is integrable